# Why is my Boolean returning True when it is supposed to be false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a function that checks if my square is a Lo Shu Magic Square. Thus I have to have the sum of each row, each column, and each diagonal all add up to the same number.

```
NUMBERS = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def checkMagicBox(box):

  isBool = True
  magicNumber = 0
  for idx in range(3):
    magicNumber += box[idx][idx]
  print(magicNumber)


  totalDiag = 0
  for idx in range(3):
    totalDiag += box[idx][2-idx]
  print(totalDiag)

  isBool = magicNumber == totalDiag

  if isBool:
    for line in range(3):
      print(sum(box[line]))

  if isBool:
    for col in range(3):
      totalCol = 0
      for line in range(3):
        totalCol += box[line][col]
      print(totalCol)

  return isBool

def main():
    print(checkMagicBox(NUMBERS))

main()
```

My problem is that my function should be showing true when it is supposed to be not true.

Comment: You can remove the second test on `isBool` - you don't change the value.  Note that an `if` statement doesn't necessarily control a single statement, it can control a block of statements (where a block is indicated by the indentation).

Comment: I also wouldn't assign `isBool` at the top of the function - you don't use it until just before you assign its actual value.

Answer (score 0):

In your code expression `magicNumber == totalDiag` is True so it is returning true. You can debug your code and check the values

Comment: In particular, 1+5+9 == 3+5+7.  I suspect the OP also needs to check if the rows and columns add to the same value too.